# How to write for loop to find particular number existing or not in multiple columns for each row in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a data frame like this:

```
abc = {'p1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1],
       'p2':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2],
       'p3':[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3]}
```

I want to add another column to find if the number 1 exists or not for every row in those 3 columns like this:

[image]

I have tried this one got nothing but error. here 1 = yes, 0 = no

```
is_1st_exist = []
for p in abc['p1'],abc['p2'],abc['p3']:
    if (p[0] | p[1] | p[2] == 1)
        is_1st_exist.append(1)
    else is_1st_exist.append(0)
```

What should I do to get below is_1st_exist column?

```
abc = {'p1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1],
       'p2':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2],
       'p3':[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3],
  'is_1st_exist?':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]}
```

Comment: You need to take a step back and learn the syntax of python. The code you posted is practically pseudocode.

Comment: Definitely sir. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compare all values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), then test if at least one value per row is `True` by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and last convert to integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(abc)
df['is_1st_exist?'] = df.eq(1).any(axis=1).astype(int)
#alternative
#df['is_1st_exist?'] = np.where(df.eq(1).any(axis=1), 1, 0)
print (df)
   p1  p2  p3  is_1st_exist?
0   1   2   3              1
1   2   3   4              0
2   3   4   5              0
3   4   5   6              0
4   5   6   7              0
5   6   7   8              0
6   7   8   9              0
7   8   9   1              1
8   9   1   2              1
9   1   2   3              1
```

If want specify columns for test by `list`:

```
cols = ['p1','p2','p3']
df['is_1st_exist?'] = df[cols].eq(1).any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over 'columns' like this:

```
is_1st_exist=[0 for i in range(len(abc['p1']))
for i in range(len(abc['p1'])):
    for k,v in abc.items():
        if v[i]==1:
            is_1st_exist[i]=1
abc['is_1st_exist'] = is_1st_exist
```

but if you have lots of problems like this to solve you may be better off using the 'pandas' or 'numpy' modules; pandas is good for tabular data of any kind, like excel, and numpy is kind of like a matlab replacement. 
The `len(abc['p1'])` is just the length of your 'rows'.